# SQL Union Help - Results Are Inverse

Tags: sql, union

So I want to combine two tables using a union with orders superseding carts. The query for the union looks like this:

```
SELECT o1.EMAILADDRESS, o1.EVENTNAME 
FROM ZZ001Email1RegionOrdersFinal  o1 
WHERE o1.EMAILADDRESS = 'andy.devoto@vividseats.com'

UNION

SELECT c1.EMAILADDRESS, c1.EVENTNAME 
FROM ZZ001Email1RegionCartsFinal c1 
WHERE c1.EMAILADDRESS = 'andy.devoto@vividseats.com'
```

Attached are the results that the order query alone has and the results the union has (which is the users cart). I am wondering why the order isn't overwriting the cart as it should.

The left image is what results from just running the top (Orders) query and the right image is what results from running the union query with results the cart when it should result the order.

[OrderResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t51ah.png)
[UnionResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4CU8.png)

Comment: Please don't post [the same question on multiple sites in the Network](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94889/sql-union-no-working-properly).

Comment: huh?  "I am wondering why the order isn't overwriting the cart as it should"

Comment: Delvin - that is what I am wondering too. 
Bob - i was told i posted on the wrong part there so i posted it here.

Comment: Then delete it on Salesforce.

Comment: bob - i get that there are rules to this but clearly i'm a beginner. I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: bob - it is now deleted. now that i solved that, could you help with my actual question?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please explain "I am wondering why the order isn't overwriting the cart as it should". Can you explain what you are expecting to see in your screenshots? What result do you want to see? Also please tag the database type (sql server, oracle, sybase?)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a table is defined as an *unordered* set of records.

The order of a query is determined by the `ORDER BY` clause.  An `ORDER BY` clause is the *only* way to guarantee record order.  You haven't got an `ORDER BY`, so your RDBMS is giving you the order that it finds convenient.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.EMAILADDRESS, U.EVENTNAME
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS OrderColumn, o1.EMAILADDRESS, o1.EVENTNAME 
    FROM ZZ001Email1RegionOrdersFinal  o1 
    WHERE o1.EMAILADDRESS = 'andy.devoto@vividseats.com'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 2 AS OrderColumn, c1.EMAILADDRESS, c1.EVENTNAME 
    FROM ZZ001Email1RegionCartsFinal c1 
    WHERE c1.EMAILADDRESS = 'andy.devoto@vividseats.com' ) U
ORDER BY U.OrderColumn;
```